# Multiline window title in titanium

Tags: titanium, titanium-mobile

I am feverishly trying to make the title of a window multiline.
I have a fairly long title and need to be able to see the whole title.

Right now the title just gets cut of and has three dots if it is longer than the window allows
But I need it to break into two lines if it is too long

My current markup looks like:

```
/////// create first starting window ////////
var startWin = Titanium.UI.createWindow({
    title: 'Some really long title that has to be wrapped',
    navBarHidden: false,
    exitOnClose: true,
    barImage: '/images/header_background.png',
    titleAttributes: {
        color: '#FFF',
        font: {
            fontSize: 20,
            minFontSize: 15,
            fontWeight: 'bold',
            wordWrap: true
        }
    }
});
```

Or can I maybe use a multiline label?

Anyone an idea ?

Thanx

My working code thanx to Sebastian

```
page_title = Ti.UI.createLabel({
    text: 'Algorithmen',
    height: 80,
    left: 60,
    right: 60,
    textAlign: 'center',
    color: '#fff',
    font: {
        fontSize: 18,
        fontWeight: 'bold',
        wordWrap: true
    }
}),
startWin = Titanium.UI.createWindow({
    titleControl: page_title,
    navBarHidden: false,
    exitOnClose: true,
    barImage: '/images/header_background.png'
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the window.titleControl with a label

```
var startWin = Titanium.UI.createWindow({
  titleControl: Ti.UI.createLabel({
    text:'Some really long title that has to be wrapped'
    font:{
        fontSize: 20,
        minFontSize: 15,
        fontWeight: 'bold'
    }
  }),
  navBarHidden: false,
  exitOnClose: true,
  barImage: '/images/header_background.png',
});
```

Comment: Perfect! This allows me to add a multiline label as title of the window.
Thank a lot I will add my code to my answer

Answer (score 0):

I have never managed to do this, so I have always hidden the title bar and created my own, with android you will need to create a custom theme to hide the title bar, also there is no title bar on iOS.

I use alloy mainly and created a nav control view that I added by reference to each page, then set the title and menu options in that.